# PHP Stack Dump Warning

Tags: php, stack, dump

I'm going out of my mind right now. I can't figure out what the heck is causing these stack dump warnings. I have PHP errors not being shown so not sure why it's even showing the warning but I just need to figure out what is happening here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

=============================================================
[Warning]: Undefined array key "userid"

Stack Dump:

errorHandler(integer(2), string("Undefined array key "userid""), string("/home/domain/public_html/prgprofile.php"), integer(40))
[/home/domain/public_html/prgprofile.php:40]

include_once(string("/home/domain/public_html/prgprofile.php"))
[/home/domain/public_html/skins/blusk/index.php:58]

include(string("/home/domain/public_html/skins/blusk/index.php"))
[/home/domain/public_html/lib/class.Skin.php:86]

Skin->ShowIndex(string("member"))
[/home/domain/public_html/index.php:28]

==============================================================

A. What could be causing this?
B. How can I stop these warnings from happening?

After user registers I get these warning.

Comment: The first thing to do is look at line 40 of `prgprofile.php` and ask yourself why that array might not have key `userid`.

Comment: This is my line 40:
    $Sess_UserId= $_SESSION['userid'];

Comment: First, distinguish the differences between warnings and errors. Secondly, use code to `check the existence` of $_SESSION['userid'] **before** using it.

Comment: give code for better understanding

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", "Warning: Undefined array key", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-warning-undefined-arr)

Answer (score 0):

Your session is not set. To remove error , you can use this

```
$_SESSION['userid'] ?? 0;
```

This will fix the warning but you will still have no userid in your session variable.